# getting data from callbacks using node "request" library

Tags: node.js, callback, request

I'm struggling with working out how to get the return data from this code example. If I try to get the cert data from the callback function its always empty. Is there something I'm missing here?

```
 var Request = require('request');

     function callhttp(host) {

     var cert = " ";

     var options = {
         url: 'https://' + host
     };

     function callback(error, response, body) {
         if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
             var cert = response.connection.getPeerCertificate();
         }
     }
     Request(options, callback);
     return cert
 }
 console.log(callhttp("www.google.com"));
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By returning 'cert' you refer to the operation as a sync one, which is not.

The correct pattern is to pass a callback function and handle the data whitin:

```
 var Request = require('request');

 function callhttp(host, cb) {

     var cert = " ";

     var options = {
         url: 'https://' + host
     };

     function callback(error, response, body) {
         if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
             var cert = response.connection.getPeerCertificate();
             cb(cert);
         }
     }
     Request(options, callback);
}

callhttp("www.google.com", function(_cert) {
    console.log(_cert);
});
```

Comment: Wow - OK. Thanks very much for this. It now works properly. Just out of interest what do the _ mean?

Comment: Nothing, just semantics for you to display the difference with the one inside the callhttp function